# 12v ac supply to 12v dc load

Tags: audio

Hi guys need advice I have a vintage Amp and the db meters lights gone out the supply voltage is ac and I can only source 12v dc leds how do I convert 12acsupply to 12dc load

Comment: Please punctuate and capitalise properly when posting. See site policy in [Write to the best of your ability](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on the site's help pages. If you add in a datasheet link for the LEDs it will be easy to give specific advice.

Comment: a bridge rectifier, electrolytic capacitor and a 12V linear voltage regulator will do the trick, provided your current requirement is not so great that it exceeds the capacity of the voltage regulator. Since you are referring to an "amp", I assume you need low noise, and although a switching buck regulator is more efficient, a linear regulator will usually have lower noise. However, linear regulator ICs generally have lower current capacity than switching regulators, so... the final answer depends upon your requirements.

Comment: Depends on the 12V DC LED you're planning to use. Some of them have protection diodes against reverse polarity so you can just replace the original bulb directly.

Answer (score 0):

This is how 12V LEDstrings are produced except you need to add a full-wave bridge to use both halves of the cycle and no (cheap) capacitor will be big enough to help to low impedance LEDs.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPx8GD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: OP does specifically say he's going to use a 12V DC LED.

Comment: TY @Finbarr , edits done